# WPFToolkit Override ColumnDataPoint Template

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I'm using the **WPF Tookit** (http://wpf.codeplex.com/) and am using the chart controls to make a column chart using **ColumnSeries**. I'm trying to override the default **ColumnDataPoint** style however when ever I run the application the columns no longer render and I see a "**System.NotSupportedException**" and "**System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException**" in the debug output log. Am I doing something wrong or is the issue with the outdated **WPF Toolkit**? Thanks.

**Includes:**

```
xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

**The Chart:**

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="columnChart" Title="Results" >
     <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries DataPointStyle="{DynamicResource ModernColumnStyle}" DependentValuePath="Count" IndependentValuePath="Method" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" />
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

**Resource with Style:**

Only change I made from the original source was that I removed the VisualStateManager stuff

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint" x:Key="ModernColumnStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint}}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" x:Name="Root">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#77ffffff" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00ffffff" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#ccffffff" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Border BorderBrush="#77ffffff" BorderThickness="1" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" />
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change "DynamicResource" to "StaticResource" like this:

```
<chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries DataPointStyle="{StaticResource ModernColumnStyle}" DependentValuePath="Count" IndependentValuePath="Method" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" />
```